# Bound Service vs Repository

Tags: android, service, repository-pattern

### Background

I am trying to understand when I should be using bound services. It seems that I could use a repository instead in most cases.

I understand the value of a bound service to be:

1. Inter process communication
2. Synchronous behavior
3. Lifecycle adherence (the bound service, if not started using `startService`, terminates when it has no bindings, and instantiates when it is bound to)

However, it seems those things can be accomplished with a `Hilt` injected repository singleton.

My current example includes an unbound foreground service which is responsible for remote uploads of aggregated data and a UI that displays that data. Both components require authentication functionality.

### Problem

To give the UI and foreground service access to authentication status and requests I could do two things:

1. Inject both with an `AuthenticationRepository`.
2. Create an `AuthenticationService` and have both components bind to it.

Option 1 feels cleaner and more understandable. Option 2 seems to have some value that I do not understand. They both offer synchrony, communication, and lifecycle adherence.

### Question

What are the pros and cons of my solutions here? How can I better define the purpose of a bound service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to understand when I should be using bound services

Most developers will not need one. More specifically, use a bound service when:

- the component really needs to be a service for other reasons, and
- you want synchronous communications with that service

Nowadays, most of the time, this winds up being an IPC scenario, either between a core OS process and your app or between two processes within your app. So, for example, a `TileService` winds up being a bound service, because that is how Google defined the contract between the service and a core OS process.

IOW, if dependency inversion (Dagger/Hilt, Koin, etc.) will solve the problem, that probably is the better choice.

Bear in mind that wide use of DI is a relatively recent Android phenomenon (within the past 5 years), so older materials might put unwarranted emphasis on bound services.

> Option 1 feels cleaner and more understandable

FWIW, I agree.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the utility of a bound service between two processes in an app? Maybe give an example and explain why DI wouldn't be a better solution if you have the time.

Comment: @LucasKivi: Common Android DI solutions do not work across processes. If you elected to have 2+ processes (e.g., UI process and foreground service process), you cannot inject the same object into both processes using, say, Hilt.

Comment: Ok thank you, that is directly applicable in my situation. I appreciate the help.