# How to make a Repository singleton for a Foreground Service and Fragments?

Tags: android, repository, singleton, dagger-hilt, foreground-service

I have a `Repository(context: Context)` class (accepts a context) that must be singleton.

In normal cases it is easy to do. But in my app, I have a `Foreground Service` that will be running even when the app is removed from the recent apps.

And I have to use the `Repository` object inside this `Foreground Service` and as well as inside other `Fragments` in the app.

**What is the best way to make the `Repository` singleton?**

Currently I am using `dagger-hilt` to inject the `Repository` inside the `Service` class. And I am not sure if it is the right way to do it.

Here are the code samples:

**MainApplication.kt**

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class MainApplication: Application() {}
```

**HiltModule.kt**

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object HiltModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun getDataStore(@ApplicationContext mContext: Context) = Repository(mContext)
}
```

**ForegroundService.kt**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ForegroundService : Service() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var dataRepo: Repository
}
```

Comment: Try to run and test your app. Everything seems right to me. Also maybe [this](https://dagger.dev/hilt/components.html) can help

Comment: I have tested it. There's a problem. When I inject the repository inside the fragment and read data from the repository, The whole application stays alive when the foreground service is running even when I remove the app from the recent apps list. I know this because i have put a log statement inside the fragment where i am reading the repository's data,  and when i save data in the repository from the foreground service, the log statement inside the fragment get called even when i close the app and remove it from the recent list.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Hilt, but you can use a bound service if you're okay with foregoing constructor injection. You could setup a binding between your activity and the foreground service, and then pass in your shared Repository instance once the service is live and has registered itself. As I understand it, this is the recommended way to communicate between an activity and service.

I think this will also help with the lifecycle issue you bring up in the comments. I'm using this approach on a foreground service that has a different lifecycle than my MainActivity, the activity gets destroyed and the service keeps running in the background, no problems. It also starts back up and syncs with the foreground process without issue. Hilt may be inadvertently causing lifecycle issues.

Edit: Just came across this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70501443/bound-service-vs-repository#comment124625667_70501514)

> Common Android DI solutions do not work across processes. If you
> elected to have 2+ processes (e.g., UI process and foreground service
> process), you cannot inject the same object into both processes using,
> say, Hilt.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ForegroundServiceConnection {

    private lateinit var mService: ForegroundService
    private var mBound: Boolean = false
    private val mConnection = object : ServiceConnection {
        override fun onServiceConnected(className: ComponentName, service: IBinder) {
            Log.d("SERVICE CONNECTED", "FOREGROUND RUNNING")
            val binder = service as ForegroundService.ForegroundServiceBinder
            mService = binder.getService()
            mBound = true
            mService.setCallbacks(this@MainActivity)
        }
        override fun onServiceDisconnected(arg0: ComponentName){
            mBound = false
        }
    }
}
```

You will also need to implement the binding in the service:

```
class ForegroundService: LifecycleService() {

    private val binder = ForegroundServiceBinder()

    inner class ForegroundServiceBinder : Binder() {
        fun getService(): ForegroundService = this@ForegroundService
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder {
        return binder
    }

    private lateinit var serviceConnection: ForegroundServiceConnection

}
```

Next, create an interface that defines the methods you want available to the foreground service, like this:

```
interface ForegroundServiceConnection {

    fun getRepositorySingleton () : RepositoryClass 

}
```

Now, go back to the activity you added the binding to, and implement the interface methods.

```
fun getRepositorySingleton () : RepositoryClass {
    return repo
}
```

Inside the foreground service, create the setCallbacks method that will receive the activity/app as an argument, and hold a reference to it, like this:

```
fun setCallbacks(app: MainActivity) {
    serviceConnection = app
    // Now you have access to the MainActivity
    val repo = serviceConnection.getRepositorySingleton()
    // Done
}
```

Remember to check for null values if you attempt to use the serviceConnection outside of this block, it may not have been created yet.

Enjoy! :)